# How to draw y on a specific interval with histogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [0, 1, 2]
y = [71.6, 18.1, 10.3]
labels = ['one', 'two', 'three']

plt.bar(x, y, width=0.8)
plt.xticks(x, labels)
plt.title("title graph")
plt.show()
```

I'm a beginner with matplotlib and I have to replace y by y = np.power(x,3) - np.power(x,2) + 1/10 on the interval [0,1[ using 10 bars

I don't know how to do this,nevertheless I've tried something but it's false :

```
x = [0, 1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
y = np.power(x,3 )-np.power(x,2)+1/10
resy = np.array(y).reshape(1,10)
resx = np.array(x).reshape(1,10)
inter = np.arange(0,0.99)

labels = ['one', 'two', 'three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten']

fig, axe = plt.subplots()

draw = axe.plot(inter,resy)
axe.bar(resx,draw,width=0.8)
```

result of the answer below

[image: graph]

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [0, 1, 2]
y = [71.6, 18.1, 10.3]
labels = ['one', 'two', 'three']

plt.bar(x, y, width=0.8)
plt.xticks(x, labels)
plt.title("title graph")
plt.show()

#replace y by y = np.power(x,3) - np.power(x,2) + 1/10 on the interval [0,1[ 
using 10 bars
x = np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)
y = np.power(x,3) - np.power(x,2) + 1/10
plt.bar(x, y, width=0.8)
plt.xticks(x, labels)
plt.title("title graph")
plt.show()
```

Comment: I posted the output from your answer above

Comment: Please make sure to post it in the relevant answer section on other answers